# Бинарные деревья и изоморфность

Tags: java, структуры-данных, бинарное-дерево

[Лучший источник](https://studfiles.net/preview/1671672/page:6/) в данном примере указано, что

> Следовательно, возникает полезное понятие изоморфизма, которое определяет, являются ли два неупорядоченных дерева по существу одинаковыми

В самом контексте есть слово **неупорядоченных**, но бинарное дерево по определению является **упорядоченным**, иначе идет нарушение правил.

> Я прошу, поясните понятие изоморфизма в понятиях бинарных деревьев.

Пишу на java.

Comment: @guerrk1n вот именно, сам мучаюсь

Comment: Под "неупорядоченным" понимается "не задан порядок ветвей"

Comment: @cppquestions можете пояснить?

Comment: Утверждение "бинарное дерево по определению является упорядоченным" неверно.

Comment: @talex почему так?

Comment: @michael_best например `new node(2, null, new node(3, null, new node(1, null, null)))` не упорядоченное дерево.

Comment: @talex разве это бинарное дерево? Если делать обход, то полученный массив не будет упорядоченный. А основная функции дерева - чтобы обход давал упорядоченный массив.

Comment: @michael_best почему вы отклонили удаление метки `java`, если вопрос не зависит от ЯП?

Comment: @michael_best "можете пояснить?": порядок - это некоторые отношение, заданное на множестве. Под отношением порядка в статье понимается порядок ветвей, то есть мы считаем одинаковыми с точностью до изоморфизма деревья 1 и 2 на рисунке 2.6, потому что ветви одни и те же, но порядок разный

Comment: там же в следующем предложении идет: _Два бинарных дерева Т1 и Т 2 изоморфны,если Т2 может быть получено из Т1 **изменением порядка ветвей** в поддеревьях._ И даже картинка есть с демонстрацией.

Comment: @grundy как бинарное дерево может быть неупорядоченным?

Comment: @michael_best, а ты видел картинку которая после определения идет?

Comment: @grundy конечно видел, мы группой обсуждали и пришли к выводу, что там ошибка, потому что нельзя чтобы бинарное дерево было неупорядочное

Comment: @michael_best, а почему ты думаешь что оно неупорядоченное? :-)

Comment: @grundy если просто поменять как на картинке(корень там **const**), то дерево обязательно станет неупорядоченным

Comment: @michael_best, кстати, _но бинарное дерево по определению является упорядоченным_ а можно ссылку на это определение?

Comment: @grundy согласен, не нашел. Но разве есть хоть какой-то смысл в неупорядоченном бинарном дереве? в нем нельзя быстро искать элементы, непонятно куда вставлять

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86989/discussion-between-grundy-and-michael-best).